Is the modulus operation multiplicative for matrix multiplication?
If A and B are square matrices with integer elements, is it true that
(A mod n)(B mod n) mod n = (AB mod n) ?

yes, matrix multiplication are just multiplications and addition for every entry

Special case of the multivariate Polynomial Congruence Rule - as in the  linked dupe, since the entries of the product are multivariate (integer coef) polynomials of the entries of $A$ and $B.\ \ $
